# unknown behavior when reloading the current page using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, undefined-behavior, reloaddata

After performing some update using javascript XMLHTTPRequest I use:

```
location.reload(true);
```

In order to get the updated page but it did not work, only if refresh manually to remove the cache!
but if I use :

```
    location.reload(true);
    return;
```

The page refresh with the newly updated content.
I found it by coincidence and I'm not able to understand this behavior.

This is an exemple:

```
function editDo(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var trgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
        e.preventDefault;
        axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost/eh/admin/activity',
                data: {
                    f_name_en: document.getElementById('edit_service_en').value,
                    f_desc_en: document.getElementById('edit_desc_en').value,
                    f_name_fr: document.getElementById('edit_service_fr').value,
                    f_desc_fr: document.getElementById('edit_desc_fr').value,               
                    f_what: "update_service"
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                location.reload(true);
                    return; 

            }, (error) => {
                //location.reload(true);
                //  return; 
            });
            location.reload(true);
                    return; 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code nobody could possibly answe... actually what is your question again?

Comment: The difference only when I add  'return' . if I add it remove the cache and I got the new content it's just a simple reload. xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          location.reload(true);
         return;
    }
};

Comment: interesting. You should post that code anyway ;)

Comment: The second last line is `location.reload(true);`, but that will reload your page, probably before the post operation has a chance to complete.  Try removing that line.

Comment: maybe I miss explained the problem. the reloading operation worked well but the content not updated in my view "so I'm talking about the navigator caching".

Comment: You might as well remove the `then` and the `error` clauses then, since they will never be invoked!  Try adding a delay with `setTimeout` so that your `location.reload()` happens after 5 seconds (just for a test).

Comment: I removed some unnecessary code for error handling just for clarity. I will try delaying without return statement and I will keep you up to date.  but in reality I don't want this behavior my modal should be hidden and refresh the page immediately with the new content. as I said my main problem is the cach

Comment: Either the cache, or your reload is happening too early, so that your server has not yet been updated (that's why I suggested the delay, to eliminate that possibility).

Comment: I'm woking on my Localhost and the reloading function fired only after receiving a response from the server. in the server side I double check if the content was updated or not. but I really like your genius idea. I could happen on high traffic in production! thanks